# Senior Capstone project. Networking design

Tags: cisco

I am still new to networking, but I am in my senior project class to get my associates. We have to design and budget a network for 4 buildings. Two are in one city and two are in another city. I plan on giving multiple options ranging from a cheap plan to a high end plan.

The WAN link is 100 Mbps but can go up to 300 Mbps, depending on the cost. We have to use Cisco equipment and EIGRP. There are roughly 1500 users in this company but they have plans to expand. I need to have high redundancy and try to maintain low cost.

So I was thinking for a high end option, I could use a Cisco ASR 1001-X Router for my headquarters, where most of the users are, and then have 3 Cisco 4331 routers on the other 3 buildings. For switches, I would use the cisco meraki MS350-48 for all the client computers. But do I need a core/distribution switch at every building to move the  large amounts of data?

Comment: What are your expected traffic patterns? There is a lot of information missing. Servers are actually off-topic here, but you should place it where it is needed. For instance, if it is primarily used by a group or department in a single building, it should be placed there. If the web server is used externally, you should place it at the site which has the link to the Internet.

Comment: So the main headquarters is where the management/admin people are, along with customer service and a lot of other users who wont be using much data.  Building 2, which is in the same city as the HQ, has the video editors and other users who will be using a lot of data. Buildings 3 and 4 will not be using much data either. I don't know the exact amount of data that each will use, so i can't be much more specific.

Comment: Those are the types of things you need to consider. You must think of how the network is used, and you must try to project the network traffic. We can't design your project for you. In the real world, things would probably be much messier, and things may need to be designed a bit differently. For instance, it sounds like you intend for all the sites to just terminate their WANs at the headquarters, but things like MPLS VPNs are used today, and those can render that too expensive or moot.

Comment: But in terms of equipment, does that sound okay? Do I need a core/distribution switch to help move the data? What about redundancy, I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a hub and spoke topology where you place your core router at your HQ, being your hub and then your remaining 3 buildings being satelites, will just require distribution switches that can also route back to your HQ building.

You need to look at how your data is going to flow. If your satelite buildings are going to access services in your HQ, you need to see what services they are going to be and how much data is going to transfer across the WAN link. This in turn will tell you if your 100/300Mbps link is going to be sufficient. If they are critical services, a redundent WAN link could be used as a backup.

Your distribution switches could be stacked, turning 2+ switches into a single switch, while plugging trunk ports to each switch and creating aggregated links for redundancy.

If you want to have a redundent gateways, you could make use of VRRP or Cisco's HSRP. Perhaps use MSTP to direct traffic based on VLAN's to specific VRRP instances, so that even numbered VLAN's flow to core router 1 and uneven VLAN's run to core router 2. Or perhaps even look at what is generating the most traffic and balance it out between two core routers.

Are the satelite buildings going to host servers that are going to be used by the building? If so, make sure they are connected to distribution switches that will aggregate the connections and use stacked switches to provide connections to multiple stacked switches from the servers.

If the servers are going to talk each other constantly, make sure that they are on the same subnet to avoid unnecessary routing and simply keep things as layer 2 where you can.

Use VLAN's and make sure you minimize your broadcast domains.

Use redundent power supplies where you see fit, use UPS' for equipment providing critical services.

The best thing to do first before you start the design process is to analyse what the requirements of the users and services are going to be. Where are things going to be hosted and where can you expect bottlenecks and single point of failure.

Then you can look at what equipment you need. Look at how many packets per second the quipment can handle, whether it can have redundent management/fabric modules.

THere is alot more information requierd to help you more but this is what I can think of right now and I hope this gives you a bit of an idea.

Comment: This helps me out a lot. I didn't even think of using satellites to link the buildings. The hard part about this project is that we were given little to no information about the amount of data being used. Pretty much what I have told you is what I know. Everything else is up to me and my best judgement.

Comment: Also, I just found out that the Cisco meraki switches cannot use EIGRP, which is a requirement for the project. So what switches do you recommend? For access switches, would the Cisco 550x work? Can you recommend a good distribution switch to connect the buildings?

Comment: Sorry, but product recommendations are not allowed here. What I would say is to look at your requirements first and then shop around. You can look on the Cisco site and look at the access and ditribution/core section to find the products Cisco has to offer. Compare the datasheets and see what fits your needs.